# Google cloud VPC Firewall rule does not show any rejected logs

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

I have Google VPC firewall rule to allow ssh(default tcp:22) access to a specific IP address (for example 1.2.3.4/32), this firewall rule has the highest priority in the VPC.
The firewall rule has logging turned on.

When looking in the Google Stackdriver Logging console i can see entries for ALLOWED connection (i.e. connection from 1.2.3.4).
When i try to ssh to this host from a host that has a not allowed IP it is being rejected by the firewall rule as expected but no log entry is showing in the Logging console.

I am assuming REJECTED entries should also be logged.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Define what you mean by not allowed? By IP address, port rule, invalid private key, etc. Edit your question with this information plus include details on your firewall rule.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I have edited the question per you comment, I hope it makes it more clear now

Comment: has anyone experienced this issue?